# Configuring gitlab-ci.yml file in Gitlab with Vue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Trying to use CI/CD with VueJs with Gitlab.

Played around with 50 different gitlab-ci.yml configurations and keep having loads of issues with different stages.

I followed the following tutorial to a T:

https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/

```
build site:
  image: node:6
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

deploy:
  image: alpine
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - rsync -rav --delete dist/ user@server.com
```

I skipped the testing phase because it keeps failing...and so why not just skip it.

If it helps, with this configuration, I keep getting the following error:
[image]

What does your gitlab-ci.yml file (that works) for a VueJS webapp look like?

Comment: Your SSH private key seems to be invalid. Make sure it starts with `-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Hi @1615903 thanks! Yes! the $SSH _PRIVATE_KEY corresponds to a "secret variable" (under settings => CI/CD => secret variables)  which starts like you mentioned. I tried copy/pasting it instead of the $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY as a string but the "----" create problems. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please reword the question. It clearly has nothing to do with vue.js if it's a SSH connection error.

Comment: @JakubKania partly agree...the error is arbitrary and just an example because I don't have the correct gitlab-ci.yml for VUE. Each build seems to be specific to a language, I'm looking for a build/deploy specific to vuejs.

Comment: @Tony Well, mkae a separete question for each error or repeat the tutorial because if it doesn't work for you you didn't follow it to a  T.

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this question yesterday while I was also researching how to set up CI/CD on Gitlab. After 24 hours of research and test. I finally got a working script. Hope this helps.

For this to work, you will need to:

- Set up a variable `STAGING_PRIVATE_KEY` in `Settings -> Variables` section of your project
- Add your ssh key to the list of know hosts on your server

Below is my final script:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build site:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install zip unzip nodejs npm -y
    - npm install --progress=false
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$STAGING_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan YOUR-SEVER-IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh -p22 root@YOUR-SEVER-IP "mkdir /var/www/_tmp"
    - scp -p22 -r /builds/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO-TITLE/dist/* root@form.toprecng.org:/var/www/form.toprecng.org/_tmp
    - ssh -p22 root@YOUR-SEVER-IP "mv /var/www/html/ /var/www/_old && mv /var/www/_tmp /var/www/html/"
    - ssh -p22 root@YOUR-SEVER-IP "rm -rf /var/www/_old"
```